# How to install XAMPP on RPI?

Tags: raspbian

Can someone please explain how I can install XAMPP on a RPI so that I can host a website? I've tried downloading the linux version but that gives a .run file. I've looked on how to open .run files but I have had no luck.

Many thanks.

Comment: You will be better off using the native LAMP stack available via apt-get than XAMPP.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I setup a webserver on Raspberry Pi running Stretch, but would work for other distros.

## Apache, PhpMyAdmin and MariaDB

```
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client

sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5

sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

## install missing sqli extension

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

## now setup password and secure your install

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

## if username and password fails then disable MySQL authenticating using plugin

```
sudo mysql -u root

[mysql] use mysql;
[mysql] update user set plugin='' where User='root';
[mysql] flush privileges;
[mysql] \q
```